# Wordpress plugin: How to stop timers running in javascript upon plugin deactivation

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins

Upon deactivating a plugin, I want to stop javascript timers. Is there a way to trigger an event in the JS that will cancel the setInterval() ? Calling wp_dequeue_script() on deactivation is not helping clients already loaded the site and plugin. I also tried admin_ajax from JS code but it is not being processed anymore as the plugin is deactivated. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The solution vary depending on how you're managing the JS and PHP AJAX callback. Considering you have not included any code, I'll give you a generic solution.

So, the first solution is independant of using the theme's `functions.php` but it's a bit randy. So, when your JS AJAX call gets the output, it'll be an error indicating that WP AJAX couldn't find the callback method you've provided or maybe it'll be empty, I didn't test this. But you gotta find that output and everytime there's a response, in your `success` method check for the output, if the output is not what you expected then just `clearInterval` the timer variable.

Another take on this would be taking help of `functions.php` in your theme. Put the AJAX callback method and hooks in `functions.php` file handling the logic and working as proxy.

In the AJAX callback method, you need to check for if the plugin is active. This, again, is all up to you but some methods of checking if plugin is active could be

```
if ( is_plugin_active( 'plugin-directory-name/plugin-main-file.php') ) {
    // yes it's active
} else {
    echo json_encode( array(
        'type'    => 'error',
        'message' => 'Plugin deactivated';
    ) );
}
```

OR

```
if ( class_exists( 'AClassInYourPlugin' ) ) {
    // yes it's active
}
```

OR

```
if ( function_exists( 'a_method_in_your_plugin' ) ) {
    // yes it's active
}
```